# Share form data between different UI states

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularJs.
I have two forms in different UI states(URL's) in the form of Step 1 and Step 2.
I am supposed to fill up Step 1 and press NEXT button which goes to the Step 2, which upon being filled gives the SUBMIT button. The combined JSON of both forms is to be sent in this step to the server. 
For the NEXT button, I have simply used $state.go(form_2_url); But when the next page form comes, all the JSON being built up till now from FORM 1 is lost. How can the data be shared among states? I have used one common controller for both the states.

How to accomplish this in AngularJS?

Comment: Post your code to exemplify what you're trying to do, then people can help.

Comment: Look into storing your data using localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the data from state1 to state2 via the params: {} option in your ui-router setup. In the controller of state2, grab that data, keep it ready for combining with the state2 data, for final submission.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service to set and store the data in and inject it in both controllers.

[Official services documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)